# Luarocks can't install a library

Tags: lua, luarocks

I want to install this library:

https://luarocks.org/modules/dodo/lua-dbus

I do

```
luarocks search lua-dbus
```

There are 0 results.

```
sudo luarocks install lua-dbus
```

doesn't install anything as well.

The problem is only with this library, because I can search for other libraries on luarocks, for example

```
luarocks search socket
```

gives plenty of matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That library (and the one which it depends on) have no versioned release yet, so they are marked as `DEV` (which you can see in the ["Versions" section](https://luarocks.org/modules/dodo/lua-dbus)).

Those libraries do not show up in searches or can't be installed by default. You need to add the "development" repository in the search:

`luarocks search lua-dbus --server=https://luarocks.org/dev`

And to the install command:
`luarocks install lua-dbus --server=https://luarocks.org/dev`

So you're not doing anything wrong, it is just that the site is not clear enough.